# ubuntu python selenium -- close terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium

I'm doing some testing on a Ubuntu terminal (14.04) using python (2.7) and selenium. I have created code that will open a browser, enter username and password information into the respective fields, and keep the browser open for one hour. The problem is, a python terminal is opened when code is run. When the browser is manually closed, the blank terminal remains. How can I get the terminal to disappear when the browser is manually closed?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://example.com")


inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
inputElement.send_keys('...')

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
inputElement.send_keys('...')

inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

while 1:
    time.sleep(3600)
    try:
       b = browser.find_by_tag("body")      
    except:
      sys.exit()
```

I should mention that I'm executing this script using a .desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

you can ping the browser once every second during the "sleep" time

```
i = 0
while i < 3600:
    browser.title
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
b = browser.find_by_tag("body")
```

Comment: Unfortunately the above solutions don't seem to be working--the browser closes immediately after opening.

Comment: @user3380034, what's the error? it works on my machine

Comment: I figured it out--There was no d alias for driver. I made the change and @3678068's solution is now working. Much appreciated!

Comment: @user3380034, o yeah, sorry, I meant `browser`.